# Change nested loop into Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm catching a DbEntityValidationException, and I want to populate a Dictionary with all the errors. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
foreach (var entity in errors)
{
    foreach (var error in entity.ValidationErrors)
    {
        validationErrors.Add(entity.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName + "." + error.PropertyName, 
                             error.ErrorMessage)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the above loop into a linq statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't change it, because the inner method has a side effect and shouldn't go into a linq statement. So the only thing would be the two for each loops which could be compacted. But due to the fact that you in your most inner method access both loop variables (entity and error) you would create an intermediate anonymous object that would hold both.

So (IMHO) in this case the linq pendant would be harder to read than this simple two stacked for loop.

```
var items = errors.SelectMany(entity => entity.Select(error => new { Entity = entity, Error = error }));

foreach(var item in items)
{
    validationErrors.Add(
        item.Entity.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName 
            + "."
            + item.Error.PropertyName,
        errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly (freehanding):

```
var errorsAsDict = (from entity in errors
                    from error in entity.ValidationErrors
                    select new { Entity = entity, Error = error})
                .ToDictionary(
                   key => key.entity.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName + "." + key.Error.PropertyName, 
                   value => value.Error.ErrorMessage);
```

If a made a typo do comment and I'll fix it.

This creates a new dictionary with your errors in it, I fail to see how you want to use it though, what is the end use, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: furthermore, you have a typo since teh name of your initial collection clashes with the bound variable "error", should be errors

Comment: @Georg Fixed as well.

Comment: For me this is not easier to read and it won't be any faster than the above code.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I totally agree with that, but the OP asked "Is it possible to change the above loop into a linq statement?", and well, it is. Therefore I wanted to know the end result; "This creates a new dictionary with your errors in it, I fail to see how you want to use it though, what is the end use, maybe there is a better way?"

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
var dict = 
    errors.SelectMany(
        entity => entity.ValidationErrors, 
        (entity, error) => new { entity = entity, verror = error }
    ).ToDictionary(
        e => e.entity.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName + "." + e.verror.PropertyName, 
        e => e.verror.ErrorMessage
    );
```

Comment: That's not another method. It's simply the code from flindeberg written with extension methods syntax.

Comment: You're right @Oliver . Maybe because i'm more used to this syntax.

Comment: I'm too, but nevertheless it is simply a code clone.